# Firebase Cloud Messaging Missing Registration

Tags: android, firebase, android-volley, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey I just added FCM to my new Website. Now I want to send notifications from my android app. Everything works fine when I do this with postman. Here are my params:

```
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Foo foo = new Foo();
                    Notification notification = new Notification();
                    foo.to="[key]";
                    notification.title="foo";
                    notification.body="abc";
                    foo.notification=notification;
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String gg = gson.toJson(foo);
                    params.put("foo",gg);
                    Log.d("PAARAMS",gg);
                    return params;
                }
```

So my params look like this:

> {"notification":{"body":"abc","title":"foo"},"to":"key"}

I also added custom header like this:

```
               @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization", "key=[key]");
                    return params;
                }
```

But all I got as Response is **MissingRegistration**

When I add

> params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

I get **BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send**

This is my request response where I get the error:

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // response
                            Log.d("Response", response);
                        }
                    },
```

The full project is on [github](https://github.com/Gnadi/Dinner)

Comment: what is key=key ?

Comment: key is my server key from my fcm project.

Comment: How are you parsing the response? It looks like the code that parses the response is not expecting JSON response (which is the response you get when you send a JSON request). Is the notification delivered to the device successfully?

Comment: I am getting the response as a string because I make a string request. No the notification is not delivered to the website. To get sure my goal is to get a push notification on my website when I click the button in my android app.

Comment: In your second attempt you sent a JSON request (when you added `params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");`). How are you parsing the response?

Comment: I think volley does that for me because I am sending a StringRequest? What type of request should I take I thought this one would be okay? I also uploaded my code on github https://github.com/Gnadi/Dinner

Comment: Did you manage to come up with the solution. Am also facing the same issue. @JohannesGnadlinger

Comment: Same problem with me. Did you solve it? If so, please post the answer

Comment: @Supradip.M  sorry could not find a solution for this but got an even better idea to solve it with an pwa (progressive web app) and topics which worked
.

Comment: @Supradip.M just found another project where I worked with fcm and it worked with topics just have a look at my git repo (https://github.com/Gnadi/GoRest/blob/master/handler/handler.go) if you got any further questions about it :)